# Where execution order on castable int

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a dataset like this:

```
OrderNumber | Amount     
------------------------------ 
123         | 100.00    
123a        | 100.00
```

What I want is a from / to in the order number like this:

```
Select * from myTable where OrderNumber > 100
```

Of course for this I have to convert my OrderNumber in a integer:

```
Select * from myTable where cast(OrderNumber as int) > 100
```

Now I get the error that 123N is not a convertable integer.

So I tried this:

```
Select * from myTable 
where isNumberic(OrderNumber) = 1 and cast(OrderNumber as int) > 100
```

But I still get the same error, even the subquery

```
Select * from myTable 
where isNumberic(OrderNumber) = 1
```

gets the correct values.

So it seems that the execution order on the different where clauses are not chained (e.g. when the first is wrong, the second and-where-clause will not be reached).

My last idea is, that I filter all not `isnumeric` data into a table - but this is so much overhead.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody wants to ask - "Is this string convertible to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care if it's not the type I want to convert to)?"

Comment: Of course, you're apparently executing `ISNUMBERIC` not `ISNUMERIC` which just tells us that you're not even showing us code you've *ever attempted to run yourself* but somehow believe exhibits the actual problem you're trying to ask us about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use try_cast as below. Try_cast basically will try to convert your values from OrderNumber column to INT. In case it failed for any non integer value exist, it will return NULL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE TRY_CAST(OrderNumber AS INT) > 100
```

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f9e1cb35e2e17b11b8e21128aa3d410b)

Comment: Tried it right now, same error - MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: I have added a DEMO link with the answer. Can you please check the link. It should work.

Comment: Okay, found the problem...  The thing is, the CAST is not only in the where, its in the select as well. AND even I make a correct TRY_CAST in the where and the "123n" should be filtered BEFORE the CAST in the Select will be reached, switching the CAST to TRY_CAST in the select did the thing.

Answer (score 1):

With a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause:

```
Select * from myTable 
where 100 < case 
  when isNumeric(OrderNumber) = 1 then cast(OrderNumber as int)
  else 0
end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=bef9d1d178b84b4a5a84398caff36498).
Results:

```
OrderNumber | Amount     
-------------------- 
123         | 100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `TRY_CONVERT`

```
Select * from myTable where TRY_CONVERT(INT, OrderNumber) > 100
```